# Leyendo un fichero, al recorrerlo con While, error de null

Tags: kotlin, windows10, intellij-idea

en este codigo de mi metodo, me he dado cuenta de que nunca llega a terminar bien el while y por lo tanto cerrarse el fichero, porque antes tengo un error de este tipo:
Excepcion leyendo fichero : java.lang.IllegalStateException: it must not be null

El fichero que necesito abrir usa un charset UTF-8 sin BOM, y necesito recorrerlo linea a linea, haciendole operaciones.

Tengo un fallo dentro del while con lo de null, pero es que no se consigo arreglarlo. ¿Alguien sabe como se podria corregir?. Gracias.

```
fun leerDatosConfiguracionFichero(ficheroConfiguracion: String){
    var numeroDePasadas = 0
    try {
        val fr: Reader = InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(ficheroConfiguracion),  "UTF-8")
        val br = BufferedReader(fr)

        //forma de resolver el BOOM
        br.mark(1)
        if (br.read() != 0xFEFF) br.reset()

        // String linea que me guardara una linea del fichero
        var linea: String
        println("* INICIO bucle while ")
        while (br.readLine().also { linea = it } != null) {
            if (linea.contains(vecesPulsadoDescargarNombre)){
                println("* Linea encontrada")
                var lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre = linea.filterNot {
                        c -> vecesPulsadoDescargarNombre.contains(c)
                }
                println(lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre)
                // ahora meto la linea dentro de mi programa para que me lleve la cuenta
                vecesPulsadoDescargar = lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre.toInt()
                println("* Imprimo ahora dentro de mi programa lo que llevo " + vecesPulsadoDescargar)

            }else{
                println("* No encuentra")
            }
            numeroDePasadas++
            println("* - Finalice ahora mismo la pasada por el bucle numero : $numeroDePasadas")
        } // acaba while
        println("* FIN bucle while ")
        // importante, cierro el FileReader
        fr.close()
        println("* - CERRE FICHERO ")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("* Excepcion leyendo fichero : $e")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te indica es que estás intentando asignar un valor null a una variable que no admite null. Concretamente, es la siguiente linea

```
br.readLine().also { linea = it }
```

Lo que está ocurriendo aquí es que lees la linea y luego intentas asignar ese valor a la variable linea, sin embargo, linea lo tienes declarado como String, por lo que no admite el valor null.

Si quieres hacerlo en kotlin, tiene una forma mucho más fácil de hacer ese recorrido, puedes usar la función de la librería estandard forEachLine, que ya hace el recorrido del fichero y no tienes que preocuparte por el Null y la variable "linea" no la necesitarás declarar, ya que será el valor de "it".

Te pongo un ejemplo de como sería

```
        // String linea que me guardara una linea del fichero
    println("* INICIO bucle while ")
    br.forEachLine {
        if (vecesPulsadoDescargarNombre in it){
            println("* Linea encontrada")
            var lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre = it.filterNot { c -> vecesPulsadoDescargarNombre.contains(c) }
            println(lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre)
            // ahora meto la linea dentro de mi programa para que me lleve la cuenta
            var vecesPulsadoDescargar = lineaResultadoDescargasEncontre.toInt()
            println("* Imprimo ahora dentro de mi programa lo que llevo $vecesPulsadoDescargar")

        }else{
            println("* No encuentra")
        }
        numeroDePasadas++
        println("* - Finalice ahora mismo la pasada por el bucle numero : $numeroDePasadas")
    } // acaba while
```

No eres el primero que se ha topado con este tema, puedes encontrar más información aquí [KT-Assignment not allowed in while expression](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/2)